# created_at overwritten by save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date, save

Hi I have an object that inherits from ActiveRecord and I pass a `created_at` field when initializing.

```
o = Object.new(created_at: "2014-01-03 03:27:18")
o.save
```

and when I check the `o.created_at`, it gives me the `Time.now` timestamp instead of the time I passed in. Shouldn't it default to the created_at field that I passed it?

Comment: You are aware that both `created_at` and `updated_at` are normally set by rails when creating/updating? The default meaning is to keep a record of when records where created or updated. Do you really want to explicitly overrule the default behaviour? otherwise I would suggest renaming your field.

Comment: Yes I am aware haha. The reason why we want to overrule this is for an internal reason. Also for tests.

Comment: Ok, hard to guess level of expertise from a short question and a fairly new user :) For tests i generally stub Time.now or use a gem like timecop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`created_on` field is automatically updated when the record is inserted to the table. You can change this by overriding `timestamp_attributes_for_update` method:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save do
    self.created_at ||= DateTime.now
  end

  protected

  def timestamp_attributes_for_create
    [:updated_at]
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey unfortunately overriding this method doesn't seem to change `:created_at` from getting overwritten.

Comment: I tried both `def timestamp_attributes_for_created; [:updated_at];end` and `def timestamp_attributes_for_created; [:created_at];end` and neither work.

Comment: @user3358302 the `before_save` is an example, which still overwrites the `created_at`, so in your case you should remove the `before_save` (I guess it is obvious, but not sure if you noticed it).

Comment: @user3358302 - Made a typo, it should be `timestamp_attributes_for_create`, no `d` at the end. I'll update the answer.